# Excel VBA to SQL Server ADODB Connection - Prompt for User ID and Password

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Excel VBA

The following ADO DB Connection string works and fetches data from the database into Excel

```
Const rspADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;" & _
"Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;" & _
"Data Source=118.aaa.yy.xx;" & _
"User ID=Username;Password=password;"
```

How do I prompt the user for input of Username and Password (at runtime) using the Data connection prompt (and not the Inputbox or a Userform in Excel)?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showpost.php?p=260530&postcount=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use  the `ado db.connection`  you can according to this [vba express post](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showpost.php?p=260530&postcount=3), code extract:

> Dim dbConnectStr As String
>   Set con = New ADODB.Connection
>
> dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=" & "Oracle_Database_Name;"
>
> con.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
>   con.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
>   con.Open dbConnectStr 'ConnectionString

I've also found you **may** need to set the `Prompt` property to `adPromptComplete`.

Comment: As I am trying to connect to an SQL Server, had to change the provider to "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" in the string above.